# Can't "addSubView"

Tags: ios, swift

Error -> 'UIVIew' does not have a member named 'addSubView'

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubView(testView)
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess, it is due to the capital letter 'V'.
Try

```
 self.view.addSubview(testView)
```